# Laravel nginx permission issue

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I've installed laravel on nginx based on [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-laravel-with-an-nginx-web-server-on-ubuntu-14-04)
. when i run my server ip address a blank page appears.
this is nginx error log:

```
2016/09/15 12:40:59 [error] 2857#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "/var/www/laravel/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in /var/www/laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)
#1 /var/www/laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(336): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)
#2 /var/www/laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(615): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)
#3 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(202): Monolog\Logger->error(Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)
#4 /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(113): Illuminate\Log\Writer->writeLog('error', Object(UnexpectedValueEx...
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "/var/www/laravel/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in /var/www/laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/laravel/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)
```

Comment: Perhaps you forgot the `-R` flag for the permission commands? Try `chown -R :www-data /var/www/laravel`, `chmod -R 775 /var/www/laravel/bootstrap/cache` and `chmod -R 775 /var/www/laravel/storage`. You can also just give `chmod -R 777 /var/www/laravel` and it'll definitely work but if someone breaks into your server, your app source files may be compromised.

Comment: I tried all the permissions you mentioned , but no luck , still the same issue

Comment: Can you run `ls -lah` in the folders `/var/www/laravel/storage` and `/var/www/laravel/storage/logs` and add the output to your answer?

Comment: I'll do that in minutes.now i'm installing  a fresh ubuntu to try all the way again. as i remember there were no `storage` folder when i installed laravel via composer, so i created it manually and then run the permission : `sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/laravel/app/storage`

Comment: solved. it was due to `laravel/app/storage`. this directory does not exists in laravel 5.2 instead there is `laravel/storage` so permission should be assigned to this directory!

Answer (score 2):

I did have the same problem with this command: `php artisan storage:link`, and I did resolved with the command `sudo` before the code. Like this:
'sudo php artisan storage:link'. I believe that if you use `sudo` you will no longer have this problem.